# Is there a way to show a lot of categories without requiring a lot of scrolling on Android?

Tags: mobile, android, categorization, mobile-application

I'm thinking of designing an Android app, however I'm falling at the first hurdle, the layout.
The app will display a large amount of categories for the user to choose from on the first screen. There's no way I can think of to lessen the amount of categories (they're food types, for instance Chinese, Thai, Italian, Greek etc), even by sub-classifying them. There are two layouts that I have come up with:

1) A dashboard (grid) with images of each type of food

2) A list view of all the different types of food, probably using some form of icon for ease of differentiation.

These are both bad options for me, I want an app that's quick and easy to use and doesn't require loads of scrolling. I could add a search bar or button to mitigate of the scrolling problems but that throws up the problem of the user calling a category something different to what I have called it.

In essence I am looking for a way to display a large number of categories on the opening screen (after splash and log in) of an app that doesn't require searching or scrolling. Is there a good way of presenting a large category list that's easy to use and quick to navigate?

Comment: The first hurdle you are actually facing is the information architecture and content design, not the layout (which is just a symptom of the problem). Think about the trade-off between having lots of categories versus the usability of the app, and you'll probably want to group them a bit more. Of course, you don't want very deep navigation for the users, so this is where going back to the drawing board and considering the IA will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using tabs where you can scroll (horizontally) easily or press it directly and inside of each tab/section the subsections with pictures? More in the way of the Android Market. It's a native component and it will work in landscape mode as well.

You can even use the first page as a lading page with offers/grid in the way that you can navigate directly from the landing page or through the tabs.

If you want to show a long list of items with sub-items in mobile device there are not too many options with a easy a comfortable navigation. We have a small screen and a lot of information to show which needs to have an easy access and use.

Comment: Hadn't considered tabs, that could very well be the way I go... I run into this problem every time I have a complex category layout to do, I thought it was time to ask the community!

Answer (score -1):

if there is more content within the categories why not go for an expandable view:

[image]